# Word for traffic running slower due to road impediments

Tags: vocabulary

What is the word for when traffic or trains run slower and with multiplie unscheduled stops because of not really being congested but because of (rail)road works or change of pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

delay[s]

Examples

> "If you can use an alternative route, please do so. If you can't, then
> expect delays when you get to the site area."
>
> **[ITV News](http://www.itv.com/news/anglia/2015-04-16/a47-at-postwick-in-norwich-to-close-eastbound-tonight/)**

---

> Information on disruptions and delays to easyJet flights is explained in this short video.
>
> [EasyJet](http://www.easyjet.com/en/help/at-the-airport/delay-and-cancellations)